# I am having trouble with logging users in and out of my blog

Tags: python, django

I am makeing a blog with Django and there is one admin account associated with the program. However, whenever I log in to the admin account and when I open a new window and go to my site, the new instance of my site is logged into my admin account. Does dose anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of session authentication. So if you log in once your session cookie will be valid throughout the browser instance until your session expires.

You can learn more about it here : [HTTP session](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Session)

you can either open new tab in `incognito mode` or in `different browser` or use `token authentication` mechanism